# Cannot fully install nvidia drivers for GTX 960M on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, gpu

I have a Lenovo Y700 laptop with GTX 960M.
On 18.04 Nvidia drivers worked just fine. I upgraded to 20.04 and installation broke. It seems like installation is somewhat successful but I can't connect to the driver.

I tried removing and reinstalling both through the UI (additional drivers tool) and through CLI, but no success.

```
$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000139Bsv000017AAsd00003802bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
driver   : nvidia-driver-440 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

$ lspci -k | grep -iEA4 "VGA|3D|Display"

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo HD Graphics 530
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
07:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo SD/MMC Card Reader Controller

$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-440
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-driver-440 is already the newest version (440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt autoremove --purge nvidia-driver-440` and then `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440`. This should solve the problem if it is related to only drivers. Keep me updated about the results.

Better you run `sudo apt autoremove --purge nvidia-driver-440 && sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440`, as you might lose the display while driver re-installation.